# How to Mask PII data in AWS ORACLE RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, amazon-rds, pii, dynamic-data-masking

I am trying to mask PII data without any encryption/decrytion at application level. WHat are the different ways to mask the data.
Azure provides out of box service, where we can give schema name and column name for maksing the data, but couldn't find anything in RDS.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no out of box service for masking data in RDS. I have seen working solutions where SQL Views were created to mask the PII data. This is simple and straightforward.

Alternatively, there are multiple 3rd party tools available for masking.